# Make simple forum that allows upvotes and downvotes

Tags: forum

I would like to create a forum online that allows upvotes and downvotes and organizes posts according to upvotes and downvotes. I remember a site a while ago that had the EXACT design I'm looking for: http://oneupme.com/. This site lets users answer a question and then vote on the answers. It organizes the answers according to number of votes. That's all I want, preferably with as minimalist design as possible. I want to use it to make study tools: for example, to remember the fact: "Kingdom, phylum, etc..."  there are certain acronyms such as "King Phillips etc..." I want to display a fact and then let users invent the acronyms and then vote on those inventions. Whoever is best will be at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the [platform](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central) that is the basis of the [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) questions and answers site, to your specific project. It supports upvoting and downvoting as well as user reputation, just like on stackexchange.